# Google chrome open image files instead of downloading it

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, download, lwc

I am trying to download a file by clicking on a link. But every time, if it is something chrome can open (such as an image) instead of downloading the file, it opens it in the new tab. What should I do to prevent it from opening the file and downlaod it? Here is my code

```
        const downloadElement = document.createElement('a');
        downloadElement.href = data;
        downloadElement.target = '_blank';
        downloadElement.download = data.split('/').pop();
        document.body.appendChild(downloadElement);
        downloadElement.click();
        document.body.removeChild(downloadElement);
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to apped link tag in body tag. Try below code it's work for me.

In `data` you need to pass base64 code. other wise it open in new tab !

```
const downloadElement = document.createElement('a');
downloadElement.download = data.split('/').pop();
downloadElement.href = data; 
downloadElement.click();
```

Comment: It still does not work, opens the link of an image instead of downloading.

Comment: In a chrome browser right ?

Comment: Yes, it is a chrome browser

Comment: You pass the image extension like `png .jpeg` in `data.split('/').pop();` this code ?

Comment: Yes it is passing the extention

Comment: `downloadElement.href = data;` In `data` what you pass ? image url ? that base64 code ?

Comment: It is an image URL

Comment: You need to pass base64 code. other wise chrome open in new tab !